# How to setup a collapsible side nav without adjusting the margins of the main content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to setup a collapsible side nav for my website. [This tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp) seems like a pretty self-explanatory example.

Problem is, I have this side nav on a bunch of different templates and now I find an issue in the part where it manually sets the main content's marginLeft property like so:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

This would be a hassle to implement in all the different templates that use the side nav, as I'd have to find every instance and add a wrapper around the main content so I can adjust the margins under one id.

Is there a better option for just forcing the content to shift right when the nav pops out without directly interacting with the main content?

Comment: Overlay the navbar on top of the main content instead of changing the margins.

Answer (score 0):

As all elements are part of the `<body>`, set its padding dynamically when showing the navigation and position the navigation absolutely:

```
body.padded {
  padding-left: 300px;
}
#mySidebar{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

Here is a simple [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/vqYqwm).